# CSS Button just sits there

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('Doing Something!');
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="myFunction()">DO SOMETHING</button>
```

I have been googling this for over an hour.  Lots of stuff about how to make buttons shimmer, dip, change colors.... not a word about how to make them do something when you press them.

Comment: How are you including your javascript in the HTML? This has nothing to with "complexity" getting out of hand lol. Also CSS doesn't perform onclick interactions, **Javascript** does

Comment: Here's an example of this working https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-chebyshev-scozz?file=/index.html - it sounds like you aren't including the javascript on the page

Comment: complexity? lol. add the function in a script tag

Comment: @otejiri because "onClick(doSomething)" is too simple...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to CSS; more details will be required--chances are the JS is missing. This should log something in the JS console. I've converted the code into a snippet, which shows that it's not explicitly a code-related issue, meaning it's almost certainly something with how the HTML/JS are being loaded.